# Регулярное выражение для возврата первого (до пробела) слова строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
string pattern = @"^\s+";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

но когда пытаюсь выполнить

```
 Match match = regex.Match("list command");
```

мне возвращает `""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы просто перепутали большую и маленькую `S`

`\s` - это пробельный символ

`\S` - это любой символ кроме пробельного, нужно написать так:

```
^\S+
```

или для верности:

```
^\S+\s
```

Comment: А `^` нужно вообще писать? Или если нужно, то нужно ли `$` закрывать?

Comment: @nick_n_a, нужно, поскольку нужно взять слово, идущее _с начала_ строки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, так нужно же получить только первое слово. А символы `^` и `$` не являются парными — их можно использовать по отдельности

Comment: Я действительно всё перепутал, только в моём случае `^\S+\s` не подойдёт, т.к. мне не нужно захватывать пробел вместе со словом, а вот `^\S+` вроде как нормально работает. Спасибо.